# How to search for a string inside a class in Squeak smalltalk ? How about inside a package?

Tags: smalltalk, squeak

I searched, and searched.

I went to IRC

Hope the question is not silly. If it was, the right string to search at google would still be much appreciated

Comment: I know about fileOut. But there has to be a better way

Comment: Not an actual answer, but see http://squeak.preeminent.org/tut2007/html/035B.html for its suggestion to leave comments to yourself to revisit particular methods in the form of actual method calls which you can easily find by looking for those senders.

Answer (score 2):

Answering such questions with the refactoring engine is quite easy. The following code finds all occurrences of `/` in the system:

```
allCodeWithSlash := RBBrowserEnvironment new matches: '/'
```

From there you can further scope the search, e.g. to inside a class:

```
allCodeWithSlashInClass := allCodeWithSlash forClasses: (Array with: DosFileDirectory)
```

Or inside a package:

```
allCodeWithSlashInPackage := allCodeWithSlash forPackageNames: (Array with: 'Files')
```

If you have an UI loaded, you can open a browser on any of these search results:

```
allCodeWithSlashInPackage open
```

If you use OmniBrowser, you can also build and navigate these scopes without typing any code through the *Refactoring scope* menu.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example that shows you all methods in DosFileDirectory containing the string '\'.

```
aString := '\\'.
class := DosFileDirectory.
methodsContainingString := class methodDictionary values select: [:method |
    method hasLiteralSuchThat: [:lit |
        (lit isString and: [lit isSymbol not]) and:
            [lit = aString]]].
messageList := methodsContainingString collect: [ :e | MethodReference new setStandardClass: class methodSymbol: e selector ].

SystemNavigation new
    browseMessageList: messageList
    name: 'methods containing string'.
```

To search a whole package, wrap the search part in:

```
package := PackageOrganizer default packageNamed: packageName ifAbsent: [ self error: 'package doesn't exist' ].
package classesAndMetaClasses do: [ :class | ... ]
```